# Import not working properly in Laravel-Excel plugin

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-excel

There are 2 tables in my application. `products` and `product_metas`. Both have `One-To-One Relationship` established.

I am using [laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/) plugin as a solution for import and export of my `products` and `product_metas` table.

Now, the export function is working completely fine without any issue. But the import is not working the way I want.

Here's the controller method for import:

```
public function postImportProducts(Request $request) {
    Excel::load( $request->file( 'productsFile' ), function ( $reader ) {    
        $reader->each( function ( $sheet ) {

            if ( $sheet->getTitle() === 'Product-General-Table' ) {

                $sheet->each( function ( $row ) {
                    echo $row->name . '<br />'; // <-- outputs the name correctly.

                    DB::statement( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' );

                    DB::table( 'products' )->truncate();

                    $product = new Product;
                    $product->name = $row->name;
                    $product->amount = $row->amount;
                    $product->save();

                    DB::statement( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;' );
                });
            }

            if ( $sheet->getTitle() === 'Product-Meta-Table' ) {

                $sheet->each( function ( $row ) {

                    DB::statement( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' );

                    DB::table( 'product_metas' )->truncate();

                    $productMeta = new ProductMeta;
                    $productMeta->product_id = $row->product_id;
                    $productMeta->description = $row->description;
                    $productMeta->title = $row->title;
                    $productMeta->keywords = $row->keywords;
                    $productMeta->save();

                    DB::statement( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;' );
                });
            }

        });
    });
}
```

I don't know what is the mistake, but I get the following `ErrorException`:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `amount`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , 2015-07-16 09:18:02, 2015-07-16 09:18:02))
```

**EDIT 1:**

Product Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Properties that are mass assignable
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'amount'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

    public function meta()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ProductMeta');
    }
}
```

ProductMeta Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductMeta extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'title', 'description', 'keywords'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but the error is quite easy to understand... Where are you adding things to the database? And in that point, why is name NULL?

Comment: check, name col in csv empty, its database issue. The error states, you trying to insert a record with empty value which is not allow.  If you want to insert as empty for Column "name" change the property of column to nulable through migrations.

Comment: @frarugi87 Even I don't understand why the name is going `NULL`. For adding the data in the database, I am using the `$product->save()` and `$productMeta->save()` method.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar the names are getting printed on the screen, have a look at the question.. I have clearly mentioned that `echo $row->name . '<br />'; // <-- outputs the name correctly.`

Comment: Do you have anything special in the model like a mutator?

Comment: Is `Product` a custom class? If so, check inside the function whether the name is saved correctly. If not, is `name` the name which is then printed? Moreover you are not setting the name in `productMeta`. Is this right?

Comment: Nothing other than `protected $fillable = ['name', 'amount']` and `protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];` for `Product` Model

Comment: @frarugi87 You can check the updated question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it and I am posting the code here for future reference, perhaps it can help others who are struggling for the same solution.

I don't know if this is the correct way, but this is what I am / I was looking for:

Here's the controller method:

```
public function postImportProducts(Request $request)
{
    $getSheetName = Excel::load($request->file('productsFile'))->getSheetNames();

    foreach($getSheetName as $sheetName)
    {
        if ($sheetName === 'Product-General-Table')
        {
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

            DB::table('products')->truncate();

            Excel::selectSheets($sheetName)->load($request->file('productsFile'), function ($reader)
            {
                foreach($reader->toArray() as $sheet)
                {
                    Product::create($sheet);
                }
            });

            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');

            //var_dump('product general done');
        }

        if ($sheetName === 'Product-Meta-Table')
        {

            // dd('loading meta');

            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

            DB::table('product_metas')->truncate();

            Excel::selectSheets($sheetName)->load($request->file('productsFile'), function ($reader)
            {    
                foreach($reader->toArray() as $sheet)
                {
                    ProductMeta::create($sheet);
                }
            });

            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
            //var_dump('product meta done');
        }
    }

    Session::flash('file_uploaded_successfully', 'File has been uploaded successfully and has also updated the database.');

    return redirect('/import-products');
}
```